# Finding how many integers divisible by n between a-b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

If I have a set of integers: $[a,b]$, how can I find the number of integers in the set are divisible by $n$? Is it possible to use a combination? Also, is there any way to display this graphically?

Comment: What is the largest multiple of $n$ that is $\leqslant b$, what is the largest multiple of $n$ that is $< a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of positive integers $\le b$ those divisible by $n$ is $$\left\lfloor\frac bn\right\rfloor$$

The number of positive integers $<a$ those divisible by $n$ is $$\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}n\right\rfloor$$

Comment: @user4140, please re-state the point. Sorry,I could not understand

Comment: @user4140: $0$ is not a positive integer, and for that reason is not to be counted even though it's a multiple of $n$.

Comment: What does that box-like syntax mean? I've only studied up to pre-calculus.

Comment: @DantheMan, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Answer (score 0):

By the division algorithm $a=kn+i$ with $i<n$ then the number of multiples is $\lfloor\dfrac{a-b+i}{n}\rfloor$if $i\neq0$ and $\lfloor\dfrac{a-b}{n}\rfloor+1$ if $i=0$